# EditText error tooltip position is off

Tags: android, android-layout

I would like to have my error tooltip displayed like in this image.

[image: Correct Position]

But mine is off like this

[image: Mine. Not good]

How can I fix this?

My layout code is below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context=".main.EditProfileActivity"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_edit_profile">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginBottom="60dp"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="56dp"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/label_margin_right"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_account_grey600_24dp" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/editTextNickname"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginEnd="40dp"
                android:hint="@string/profile.nickname"
                android:maxLength="16"
                android:maxLines="1"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:textSize="16sp" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/buttonNicknameClear"
                android:layout_width="24dp"
                android:layout_height="24dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|right"
                android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                android:background="@drawable/ic_close_grey600_24dp"
                android:onClick="onNicknameClearClicked"
                android:padding="0dp"
                android:visibility="invisible" />

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/label_margin_right"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_email_grey600_24dp" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/editTextEmail"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginEnd="40dp"
                android:hint="@string/profile.email"
                android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
                android:maxLength="30"
                android:maxLines="1"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:textSize="16sp" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/buttonEmailClear"
                android:layout_width="24dp"
                android:layout_height="24dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|right"
                android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                android:background="@drawable/ic_close_grey600_24dp"
                android:onClick="onEmailClearClicked"
                android:padding="0dp" />

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

This happens to both first and second edit text.
What am I doing wrong?

EDIT:
I am adding extra code for more information.
This is the parent layout file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context=".main.EditProfileActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/content_edit_profile" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: This is happening in all activities in this project but not in other projects... Hmmm... weird..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Removing
`app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"` fixed the problem!

Thank you all!

Answer (score 0):

Try remove

```
android:paddingBottom="56dp"
```

Comment: Thank you for posting an answer. Actually, I added that line to help solve the problem. Meaning... it's the same whether that padding is there or not. :(